# Selecting which value to have a unique id on model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have two models Deals and Restaurants

I want to display the deals for each restaurant.  I do not want them linked on `:restaurant_id`, rather i want them linked on `:restaurant_name`.

What I cant figure out is how to link them on `:restaurant_name` in the controller

```
restaurant controller

def show
    @restaurant = Restaurant.find(params[:id])
    @deals = @restaurant.deals
end



show.html.erb

<% restaurant.deals.each do |deal| %>
       <h2><center><%= deal.day %></center></h2>
<% end %>
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: Do you mean something like this?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17755815/ruby-on-rails-find-by-field-other-than-id

Comment: @Matt, I think [that question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17755815/ruby-on-rails-find-by-field-other-than-id) refers to `find`, but the OP is asking about `belongs_to`

Answer (score 1):

> I want to display the deals for each restaurant. I do not want them linked on :restaurant_id, rather i want them linked on :restaurant_name.

From a database perspective, assuming a relational database, your `deals` table will have a **foreign key** that **references** `restaurants`.  Now that you know what to call it, this part of the [`belongs_to`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-belongs_to) documentation should answer your question:

> :foreign_key
>
> Specify the foreign key used for the association. By default this is guessed to be the name of the association with an “_id” suffix ...

Now that you know *how* to implement your **association**, I should point out that many restaurants in the world share the same name, so `restaurant_name` may be a poor choice of foreign key.

Comment: +1 for the figure it out methodology and for pointing out that this is probably a poor design concept as I agree completely on both fronts. Although I did specify an answer as well.

Comment: Ya i agree about poor design, its not so much that I am going to do it this way, as much as it is I want to know how to do it that way.  Thanks though.

Comment: If i dont add by name, than everytime I add a deal I have to remember the restaurant_id?

Answer (score 0):

If you must which might I say seems like a bad idea because if the name changes the chain breaks.

```
class Restaurant 
   has_many :deals, foreign_key: "restaurant_name", primary_key: "name"
end
class Deals
   belongs_to :restaurant, foreign_key: "restaurant_name", primary_key: "name"
end
```

This assumes that the model `Restaurant` uses `name` instead of `restaurant_name` but the concept is `has_many` `foreign_key` will be the key to use in the other table and `primary_key` will be the link in the current table.`belongs_to` `foreign_key` will be the key to use in the current table and `primary_key` will be the key in the other table.