# One-to-Many relation using another field except id without bad design of database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, activerecord, database-design

I have two models, Restaurants and Deals.  One restaurant has many deals and deals belong to restaurants.

There will be no logging in to edit restaurants, only the admin (me) will be able to.

Currently the key between the two models is the `:restaurant_id`.  The problem is, when I go to add a new deal for a restaurant I have to enter in the `:restaurant_id` manually.  For obvious reasons this will not scale.

I thought about making the primary key the `:restaurant_name`, but decided that is a poor design.

Any thoughts as to how I can add deals for restaurants without having to manually enter the `:restaurant_id`?

Comment: Instead of a text field, why not populate a dropdown with the name and id?

Comment: I thought about that, but if I have 200+ restaurants that doesn't seem like a scalable solution.

Comment: I suggest if restaurant had location, you can use restaurant_name, and restaurant_location as primary key.

Comment: Auto complete? Really, how do you expect it is going to work? You're going to have to get the info somewhere... Maybe you can link from the restaurant list in the admin..

Comment: I don't understand the question, do you have a webpage to edit this stuff or are we talking about a console or something, just search for the restaurant record and add new deals from there.. what am i missing.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Selecting which value to have a unique id on model](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25693438/selecting-which-value-to-have-a-unique-id-on-model)

Comment: Ya it's a Website. How do you select the Id for a deal without having to login as a restaurant.

Comment: No its not a duplicate, I had asked that question previously, but decided to go with ID instead of name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the restaurant ID into the form as a parameter. Put a link on the restaurant page that is visible only to admins:

```
link_to "Add deal", new_deal_path(restaurant_id: @restaurant.id)
```

The restaurant ID is passed in with the "new" request. Catch it in your deals controller:

```
def new
  @deal = Deal.new
  @deal.restaurant_id = params[:restaurant_id]
end
```

When the new deal form appears, the restaurant ID field will be prepopulated.